# How to Identify variables and it's assigned values from a text file in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file string saying "((A=1 AND B<5) OR (C = FALSE))". Is there any predefined algorithms to search the input text for identifying A, B and C with the values assigned or in a way to identify the braces so as to process the operations. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: from what I understood you might be looking for regex

Comment: regex will work when the format is the same like((x AND y) OR (C). What i wanted to understand is whether there is a way to understand the "parameters" like in the posted question A,B or C then subsequently finding the related values.

Comment: What are the parameters you are talking about? You mean how to solve the (x AND y) or C thing? There are libraries for this. Try z3